# How to automatically `ecryptfs-mount-private` on `gdm` login in Fedora 27?

Tags: fedora, gdm, ecryptfs

I have installed Fedora, but used existing `/home` partition from previous Ubuntu install:

- partitions:

  - `/boot/efi`,
  - `/` (formatted during install),
  - `/home` (kept from Ubuntu),
- user was set-up with same username and password as I had on Ubuntu install.

After installation, I couldn't login. So, I installed packages `ecryptfs-simple.x86_64` and `ecryptfs-utils.x86_64`.

To successfully login with mounted `/home/<username>` I have to:

1. login to terminal,
2. run `ecryptfs-mount-private`,
3. login through gdm.

Direct login through `gdm` fails.

How can I make `gdm` to automatically run `ecryptfs-mount-private` when logging in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was SELinux issue. I solved it by setting up proper security contexts for home and ecryptfs stuff. Run this with unmounted ecryptfs home:

```
chcon -u unconfined_u -t user_home_dir_t /home/<username>/
chcon -u unconfined_u -t ecryptfs_t /home/.ecryptfs/<username>/.ecryptfs/
chcon -u unconfined_u -t ecryptfs_t /home/.ecryptfs/<username>/.ecryptfs/*
chcon -h -u unconfined_u -t user_home_t /home/<username>/* /home/<username>/.*
chcon -h -u unconfined_u -t ecryptfs_t /home/<username>/.ecryptfs /home/<username>/.Private
```

I have done other experimenting previously, which may have some effect:

- enabling `ecryptfs` home encryption in SELinux: `setsebool -P useecryptfshome_dirs 1`
- configured pam to use ecryptfs:

  - setting `USEECRYPTFS=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig`
  - regenerating `authconfig --enableecryptfs --updateall`

Check `grep ecrypt /etc/pam.d/*`:

```
/etc/pam.d/postlogin:auth        optional      pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
/etc/pam.d/postlogin:password    optional      pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
/etc/pam.d/postlogin:session     optional      pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
/etc/pam.d/postlogin-ac:auth        optional      pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
/etc/pam.d/postlogin-ac:password    optional      pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
/etc/pam.d/postlogin-ac:session     optional      pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
```

I hope I didn't miss anything in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tested setup on Fedora 27:

```
1. Find out the UUID of the home partition you're trying to mount: blkid
2. edit /etc/crypttab and add the following line:
my-encrypted-home UUID="<UUID-from-above-command>" none luks
3. edit /etc/fstab and comment out the previous home entry and add the following:
/dev/mapper/my-encrypted-home /home     ext4    defaults    1 2
```

Reboot, carefully. Plymouth will prompt you for your password. If you get stuck at boot, reboot and edit the grub entry to disable Plymouth (the splashscreen, instructions available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98566/how-do-deactivate-plymouth-boot-screen)) and wait the timeout period for systemd service files to fail (1min 30s). You will be prompted to enter into recovery mode by logging in as root. Fix the error and reboot.

Comment: It's not partition, which is encrypted. But, the home folder of user is encrypted: `/home/<username>`